# Issue with jQuery selector filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I am trying to select all links on a page that are not mailto,  and tel links. Based on some of the earlier discussion I used the following

```
let links = $("a:not([href^=mailto],[href^=tel])");
```

this seems not to work, returned array of links does contain mailto,  tel  links

any idea on what is wrong in the above selector filter??

Comment: this works here https://jsfiddle.net/3h2qr29v/ (please provide your own HTML document, it must have something strange so that you thought it did not work the way you want).

Comment: The selector works fine. Need more information.